# use multiple between clause for same column

Tags: mysql, sql, between

I want to use multiple between clause for same clause.

I tried the following query but its not working

```
select id from test where 
(id between 11123745 and 11182111)
and (id between 11182962 and 11182968)
and (id between 11183172 and 11183176)
```

My query returning nothing , how can i make this query work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not physically possible to meet those conditions under any circumstances. You need to use OR.

Answer (score 2):

Your intervals are not overlapping and therefore, combining them with `AND` does not leave any id to be matched. Combine them using `OR` like this:

```
SELECT id FROM test 
WHERE 
  (id BETWEEN 11123745 AND 11182111)
  OR (id BETWEEN 11182962 AND 11182968)
  OR (id BETWEEN 11183172 AND 11183176)
```